# Updating a textfield via JavaScript forces cursor to the end

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a JavaScript (`jQuery`) function to force uppercase in a textfield. The problem is that if a user types, then tried and use the arrow keys, or clicks into the start of the field and types again, it forces the cursor back to the end of the textfield.

See the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Msh7P/1/

Type anything, then try and use the left arrow key, or click to the start of the textfield and type.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS as suggested, or you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#username").bind("input paste", function() {
        $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    })
        .bind("keydown", function(e) {
            e.shiftKey = true;
        });
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with just CSS:

```
#username { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

Comment: Nice, but I have other JS functions with the same exact problem like only allow alphanumeric, etc.

Comment: It's one less problem you need to solve though. If you have a lot of fields that need validation it'd be worth making use of a validation plugin like [this one](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

Comment: One important thing to note, the value is NOT stored in the database uppercase, it is stored as typed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because you are removing from the DOM the contents that the cursor was on and then replacing them with new contents. You are going to need to keep track of the cursor reference and then manually set the position on it in the new contents.